# Julia: How to find best fit curve / equation when I have a plot?

Tags: plot, julia

Julia: How to find best fit curve / equation when I have a plot?
I have a plot which I made with map but I need to find a quadratic equation that fits this?

Comment: Having a plot is irrelevant to being able to estimate coefficients for a quadratic fit. Use a 2nd order linear regression if you think that's appropriate. That said, plotting can be used diagnostically, i.e., to see if a quadratic might be appropriate. A plot is useful if you don't know the parametric form, and want to see if it might be linear, quadratic, cubic, exponential, negative exponential, hyperbolic, etc.

Comment: Have a look also to LsqFit.jl for general curve fitting

Answer (score 4):

As said in comments, having a plot is not really relevant here; only the data itself is. You can use packages such as `GLM` to build (Generalized) Linear Models of your data, and possibly plot them or use them to predict new outcomes.

Here is a simple example. Let's first create sample data:

```
using Plots
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(x = sort(rand(100)))
df.y = 1 .+ 2*df.x .+ 3*df.x.^2 .+ 0.1*randn(100)  # y = 1 + 2x + 3x² + noise
scatter(df.x, df.y, label="data")
```

and build a 2nd order linear model out of it:

```
using GLM
model = lm(@formula(y ~ 1 + x + x^2), df)  # Note how the formula looks exactly like the model you want to build
plot!(df.x, predict(model, df), label="model")
```

you should get something like the following:

```
julia> model
StatsModels.TableRegressionModel{LinearModel{GLM.LmResp{Array{Float64,1}},GLM.DensePredChol{Float64,LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}}},Array{Float64,2}}

y ~ 1 + x + :(x ^ 2)

Coefficients:
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
               Coef.  Std. Error       t  Pr(>|t|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)  1.04201   0.0073252  142.25    <1e-99    1.02747    1.05655
x            2.04349   0.0332272   61.50    <1e-78    1.97754    2.10944
x ^ 2        2.95854   0.0321212   92.11    <1e-95    2.89478    3.02229
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

The [Polynomials](https://juliamath.github.io/Polynomials.jl/stable/) package is a bit less intimidating than [GLM](https://juliastats.org/GLM.jl/v0.11/). You can use the `fit` function in that package to obtain a `Polynomial` of best fit for any provided order (degree). Given some arbitrary `(x,y)` data, you can create and plot the polynomial of best fit as below.

```
julia> using Polynomials

julia> x=1:10;

julia> y=rand(10);

julia> quadfit=fit(x,y,2)
Polynomial(-0.06970526100724156 + 0.1638766946706202*x -0.008058423435867207*x^2)

julia> using Plots

julia> plot(x,y,label="Data")

julia> plot!(quadfit,x[1],x[end],label="Quadratic Fit")

julia> savefig("Data and Curve Fit.png")
```

[image: Data and Curve Fit]